# How to unselect a combobox item?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm populating a combobox as follows:

```
cboMonth.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToList();
```

I also have the following event:

```
private void cboMonth_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something...
}
```

The problem is that when I'm setting the datasource, the event is being raised. I need for the event to be raised only when the user actually selects an item.

Is it possible to avoid raising the event when setting the datasource?

Comment: Remove the handler or just use a flag to ignore the change while messing with it

Comment: use selectedindexchanged event

Comment: The [`SelectionChangeCommitted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx) event is raised only when the user changes the combo box selection.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the handler before changing the selected item:

```
cboMonth.SelectedItemChanged -= cboMonth_SelectedValueChanged;
cboMonth.SelectedItem = null;
cboMonth.SelectedItemChanged += cboMonth_SelectedValueChanged;
```